# PHP login based on a password parameter

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm learning PHP now, and I'm trying to find out whether or not the following code structure has any faults:

```
$loggedIn = false;
if (isset($_GET["userpass"])){
    if (strcmp($_GET["userpass"], $correctPassword) == 0) {
        $loggedIn = true;
    }
}
```

To me, it seems pretty bullet-proof. If the password isn't set, then the code doesn't execute. And if it is, then the user actually has to supply the correct password. Anything obvious I'm missing?

**Note:**
`$correctPassword` is defined in an external file, not accesible to the public

**Update:**
Can the user of this website explit the script so that he can log in to any arbitrary account? As in, this piece of code always sets `$loggedIn = true;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not secure at all.

Apart from the `GET` issue (use `POST`) and the hashing issue (use [bcrypt](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)) already mentioned, and the fact that `==` is not timing safe (use [hash_equals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php)), an attacker can log in without knowing the password like this:

```
login.php?userpass[]=1
```

The reason for this is that `strcmp("STRING", [ARRAY])` returns `NULL`, and `NULL == 0` is true. You should pretty much never use `==`. Always use `===` for type-safe checks.

Answer (score 9):

Checking passwords / sending passwords via `$_GET` (in URL) as a absolutely nogo. You have to send that credentials via `$_POST`, using a `<form>` or Ajax.
You also don't need to use `strcmp()`, a simple comparison for example `if("pw" === "pw")` is enough.

Why is `$_GET` or passwords in url bad? So many reasons, it is just evil. Example, every logging between you and the website (browser, your provider, proxy, vpn, etc..) can see the password.

Another thing as that you never ever should save a password in plain text wherever it is possible. Always use a hashing algorithm with salts. Example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: You're wrong about `also when your site use https`. True reasons of `$_GET usage is bad` are 1. server logs, 2. browser cache, 3. leakage referers.

Comment: v@vp_arth Ok, you are right, didn't knew that.

Comment: To add to @vp_arth's comment: Without https, using POST instead of GET still leaves the data visible (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725795)) to all parties that are involved in the transportation of it. The only advantages (IMHO) of POST over GET are less restrictions on length/format and avoiding accidental publishing of your credentials when copying from the address bar to publish a link.